# Tableviewcell how to give alternate cell colour to group of items

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview with a summary page of specific data. In that the data comes in a such a way Example 
first row - 1
second row - 1
third row - 1
fourth row - 2
fifth row - 2
sixth row -3
seventh row - 4
 How can I give cell background colour grey to all row having 1, red to all row having 2, again grey to all row having 3 and red to all row having 4

Comment: could you please add what data you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the color of the row to change based on some value you can just use `cell.backgroundColor` to assign it after a check on the value you're interested in. For example let's say that value is in the variable *value*:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

/* your other code */

if (value%2 == 1)
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
else
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```